# Using hyperlinks and passing filter parameters

Tags: filter, sharepoint-2007, hyperlink

I am building a service catalog site using Sharepoint Designer 2007 and Sharepoint 2007 Server. I'm relatively new with both and have three questions for which I have been unable to find solutions. I'm sure I just pose it wrong when doing searches.  :o)

I built 3 lists - Categories, Services, and Offerings. Each category has many services and each service has many offerings. Services have a look-up field for category and offerings have a look-up field for service.

On the home page, I want to display the list of categories and allow the user to select a category and go to a category page that displays all the services in that category. I would then like to do the same on the category page to allow them to select a service and see its offerings.

My three questions are:

1) When I display a list (I'll show only the category name which is the Title field), how can I have that display include a link directing them to another page? Extra bonus points if the link can be the actual category name field or a button in front of it - something like that.

example:

**Service Categories** (select one to see the services included)

- Infrastructure Services
- Mobile Services
- Professional Services
- Workplace Services

2) How can I pass the selection (in this case the category name) and use it as a dynamic filter on the next page when I display the next list (in this case the services in the selected category)?

3) Can this be done just using Sharepoint Designer or will I need to get into the code?

Today the category list on the home page is hard-coded with links to separate category pages with hard-coded filters. When a new category is added, I will have to update the home page and add another category page. I would prefer this to be more dynamic by generating the category list on the home page from the Category list, allowing them to select one of the categories and then passing the selection to a single category page which displays services filtered by the passed category. This way the only updates needed will be to add new categories to the Category List, new Services to the Service list and so on.

My example uses a hierarchy of pages although I suppose that may not be necessary if it's possible to all of this on a single page. Just another thought.

Thank you for any suggestions or advice you might have!

Comment: I finally found an article (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/connect-two-data-views-HA010169133.aspx) that provides information about connecting data views using the Web Part Connection Wizard. So far it seems to do what I want.

Comment: The only issue is the multi-line text fields are displaying the HTML tags  - <div> </div> etc.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but I understand the fix for the HTML tags showing can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/09/20/using-disable-output-escaping-in-data-view.aspx